# Need help trying to EagerLoad some data in EntityFramework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression, predicate

I'm trying to do some eager loading on an EF Entity.

so, if the entity is called `Orders` .. then I guess i would do the following...

`_someContext.Orders.Include("Whatever") ....`

But the problem is, I have a method like the following ...

```
public IQueryable<Order> Find(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> predicate)
{
    return CurrentContext.Orders.Where(predicate);
}
```

which works great .. but can i leverage the `Expression` predicate to include the `Include("whatever")` in there, instead of having to add another method parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. Since the predicate and [**ObjectQuery.Where Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx) in genral has nothing to do with eager loading by Include. You can create a extension method though, but that does not save you from having yet another parameter for specifying the include:

```
public IQueryable<Order> Find(Expression<Func> predicate, string include) {
    return CurrentContext.Orders.Where(predicate, include);
}

public static ObjectQuery<T> Where<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string include) {
    return (ObjectQuery<T>)entity.Include(include).Where<T>(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Yeah -this was what i did a few hours ago .. sorta. I didn't bother with the extension method but just went ahead and did added another string[] includeAssociations parameter to my Find(..) method(s).